# How to add GIF images to Assets folder and load them in UIImageView programmatically

Tags: ios, uiimageview, animated-gif, xcasset, swift2

I am trying to put my @2x and @3x GIF images into the Assets folder in Xcode. I have tried the following links but it didn't work for me.
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462747/how-to-add-gif-images-to-asset-catalog-in-xcode5) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081642/adding-gif-files-to-xcode-assets-folder).

I am currently loading the GIF files by adding them to my project bundle and accessing it using this

```
let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle()
            .URLForResource("phone_animation", withExtension: "gif")
```

But I want to load them from my Assets folder. Is there a way I can do it? And how do I load them into my imageview after adding it to Assets?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to your comment, this is the solution that you are searching:

1. make an extension of UIImage which uses SwiftGif:

   ```
   extension UIImage {
     public class func gif(asset: String) -> UIImage? {
       if let asset = NSDataAsset(name: asset) {
          return UIImage.gif(data: asset.data)
       }
       return nil
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then tuning @Ganesh suggestion with the extension you might do something like:

   ```
   imageView.image = UIImage.gif(asset: "YOUR_GIF_NAME_FROM_ASSET")
   ```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Although it is not possible to add 2x and 3x GIF in the same dataset is it?

Comment: @Amogh I guess It should be possible (I tried in my local test)

Comment: how are you doing it? I am using xcode 7.3 and I am not getting option to add another GIF to the same dataset

Comment: I am running Xcode9 and I have possibility to add 1,2,3x. Check to have selected "Individual Scales" for "Image Set/Scales"

Comment: could you please tell me the code in your Contents.json file?

Comment: {
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "mygif.gif",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "mygif@2x.gif",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "mygif@3x.gif",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}

Answer (score 5):

To load gif into UIImage I suggest two libraries

1) you can use this [library](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif)

simply you can load it into UIImageView

```
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "logo-animation", withExtension: "gif")!)
let gifImage = UIImage.gif(data: data!)
imageView.image = gifImage
```

2) Or you can use this [library](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)

```
import FLAnimatedImage
```

then add outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var fashImage: FLAnimatedImageView!
```

then use this code

```
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "logo-animation", withExtension: "gif")!)
fashImage.animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: imageData)
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I want to load GIF from Assets folder only

Comment: give gif name directly which is in your asset

Comment: @Ganesh the library seems to be not supporting asset name, only full path from bundle

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini library will support asset name check it clearly

Comment: @Ganesh I checked again, according to this: https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif/blob/master/SwiftGifCommon/UIImage%2BGif.swift UIImage can be initialized only from: Data, url as String, or bundleURL as String. So there is no way to use resource from *.xcassets furthermore you can try making a test project and see that you'll receive: SwiftGif: This image named "YOUR_GIF_NAME" does not exist

Comment: any solution to load gif from Assets folder to FLAnimatedImage? Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "logo-animation", withExtension: "gif") doesn't work for assets folder access