# Loading GIFs in Xcode using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have looked online for many solutions on how to load a GIF in Xcode using Swift. But, all of them uses a lot of memory in the iOS App. These are the solutions I tried till yet! Could anyone please recommend me a better solution on loading a GIF in Xcode using Swift. Thanks for the help!

[How to add GIF images to Assets folder and load them in UIImageView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468367/how-to-add-gif-images-to-assets-folder-and-load-them-in-uiimageview-programmatic)

[How to load GIF image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/how-to-load-gif-image-in-swift)

Comment: I've tried [SwiftGif](https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif) and [SwiftyGif](https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif). I recommend SwiftyGif (takes a *lot* less memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have option like https://cocoapods.org/pods/Gifu framework as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I installed the framework through CocoaPods and changed the UIImage class to GIFImageView. But, could you please explain to me how can I make the GIF start animating from View Controller as I have followed the instructions but still no success. Thanks!

Comment: The one by 
Rebeloper - Rebel Developer?

Comment: Yes exactly  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1HthQ2oxUI

Comment: It gives an error while adding in Swift Package Manager. Any solution?